# How to Write Multiple CSV from List of Dataframe at once in R?

Tags: r, loops, csv, dataframe, datalist

I have thousands `.csv` files which consists this information:

```
Year  HS
1956  1.098
1956  1.785
1956  0.987
....
2012  1.341
```

What I should be doing are:

1. Found Maximum HS for each Year on each file
2. Write thousands separate `.csv` files which hold information of point 1

As far (also by help in this forum), I've a list of thousands dataframes of point 1 with this script:

```
    temp <- Sys.glob("*.csv")
ag <- lapply(temp, function(f) 
  aggregate(HS ~ Year, read.table(f, header = TRUE, sep = ";"), max))
```

The list look like this:

```
[[1]]
   Year    HS
1  1956 2.172
2  1957 1.831
3  1958 1.713
.....
56  2011 2.332
57  2012 2.917

[[2]]
   Year    HS
1  1956 2.111
2  1957 1.864
3  1958 1.135
.....
56  2011 1.032
57  2012 2.341
.....
until thousands dataframes
```

I am trying to write `.csv` files from those list by applying these script:

```
    temp <- Sys.glob("*.csv")
ag <- lapply(temp, function(f) 
  aggregate(HS ~ Year, read.table(f, header = TRUE, sep = ";"), max))
for(i in 1:length(ag)){
  write.csv(ag[i],file="out[i].csv")
}
```

But it only create `out[i].csv` which consists information of first dataframe of `ag`

I am also trying this script:

```
temp <- Sys.glob("*.csv")
ag <- lapply(temp, function(f) 
  aggregate(HS ~ Year, read.table(f, header = TRUE, sep = ";"), max))
lapply(ag, function(a) 
  write.csv(a, file="out[a].csv"))
```

And again, it only create `out[a].csv` which consists information of first dataframe of `ag`.

It seems that I fail to set the loop both to 'call' the dataframes on the list and to create sequential output `.csv` name. Is there any suggestion for this issue?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
write.csv(ag[i],file=sprintf("out%d.csv",i))
```

or

```
write.csv(ag[i],file=paste0("out",i,".csv"))
```

I wasn't sure whether you wanted to square brackets in the file name.  I would advise against it.

Comment: It works! Thank you very much~

No, I don't want the square brackets. It just my fail attempts to get sequential output file's name haha.

Comment: you're encouraged to click on the check-mark to accept the answer if it solved your problem